# Powershell Pipeline Argument not gettings passed to Set-ADUser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've been banging my head against the wall for the past few hours, I'm sure it's because I don't quite understand something about how @{} and $_ work.

First the code:

```
Get-ADUser username -Properties mail | Set-ADUser -replace @{"proxyaddresses"="SMTP:"+$_.mail}
```

As you can see I'm trying to update the proxyaddresses fields with the user's email address.

Instead only the string is pulled:(output: `proxyaddresses    : {SMTP:}`) and the pipeline is ignored, I'm assuming it's because it's empty for some reason, but it's not clear to me why.

I've tried variations such as `"proxyaddresses="SMTP:$($_.mail)"` I tried using default properties that are always sent with `Get-ADUser` such as `UserPrincipalName`

I know that something like this is possible because of this http://www.itprotoday.com/management-mobility/more-flexible-active-directory-one-liner and mutiple answers on SO using some variation of the linked example.

When I assign a variable to `SMTP:$_.mail` and then use that in the field instead like so:

```
Get-ADUser username -Properties mail | %{ $smtp = "SMTP:"+$_.mail 
$_|Set-ADUser -replace @{"proxyAddresses"=$smtp}
```

This works (output: `proxyaddresses    :{SMTP:emailaddress@domain.com}`). If I leave out the string like so: `@{"proxyaddresses"=$_.mail}`

I get the following error:

> Set-ADUser : Cannot bind parameter 'Replace' to the target. Exception setting "Replace": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
>
> At line:1 char:58

I'm not sure what this means.

I'd like some variation of my initial idea to work, but I'll settle for the workaround using an extra variable if there's no other way.

**EDIT:** There seems to be some confusion about what I'm asking, so I'll clarify:

**Is there a way to use the pipeline variable `$_` without a script block inside a hashtable, (inside a script block requires double piping like [@TheIncorrigible1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51196410/5965361) suggested in his first answer.)?**

EDIT: Based on [this](https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2016-11-06-powershell-hashtable-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about/#custom-expressions-in-common-pipeline-commands) it seems this should not be having any issues.

Comment: Btw, for testing I'd advise against playing with `proxyaddresses` I learned this the hard way when I left an error on my account and now I can't access email locally until the DCs replicate... you can use any unused extensionAttribute or invent your own test attribute and play with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ForEach-Object` to access the pipeline in the way you're trying, otherwise it doesn't know what your pipeline object (`$_`) is:

```
Get-ADUser -Identity username -Properties mail |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_ | Set-ADUser -Replace @{ 'proxyaddresses' = 'SMTP:' + $_.mail }
    }
```

Or the `-PipelineVariable` common parameter which explicitly assigns `$_` to a variable:

```
Get-ADUser -Identity username -Properties mail -PipelineVariable user |
    Set-ADUser -Replace @{ ProxyAddresses = "SMTP:$($user.mail)" }
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it might work, do you know the reason that I need to assign a special pipeline variable, and I can't just use `$_`?

Comment: @YizBorol My guess: without `foreach`, the pipeline isn't enumerated/variable assigned without a scriptblock `{}`.  You can do an implicit `foreach` with a scriptblock: `Get-ChildItem | Get-ChildItem -Path {$_.FullName}` for example but the parameters have to be explicitly called.

Comment: `-PipelineVariable` still doesn't fix the issue. Thanks for the suggestion though. I still get just the first part of the string.

Comment: I've chosen to mark this as the answer despite not fully answering my question, as it's the closest and I think the issue is some undocumented bug in how powershell handles hashtables with the pipeline variable.

Answer (score 0):

ProxyAddresses is an array where the Primary Email address is set like `SMTP:primary@example.com` but there can and will be other elements there too like alias email addresses (that have the lowercase `smtp:` prefix), SIP: addresses etc.

**NEVER** try to simply overwrite whatever is already there by a single string found in the `mail` attribute of the user object, but merge them with the ones you want to add. Selectively replace the ones you want to be changed and build an array of valid addresses.

Basically you do

```
$oldErrorAction = $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

$user = Get-AdUser -Identity $SAMAccountName -Properties mail
$primaryEmailAddress = $user.mail
$externalAddress = "smtp:<WHATEVER ALIAS YOU WOULD LIKE FOR THE USER">

$mailProxies = @("SMTP:$primaryEmailAddress", "smtp:$externalAddress")
# add more to this array if need be
$newProxies = @{'ProxyAddresses' = $mailProxies}

try {
    $user | Set-ADUser -Clear ProxyAddresses
    $user | Set-ADUser -Add $newProxies
}
catch {
    Write-Warning "Could not set ProxyAddresses: $($_.Exception.Message)"
}

$ErrorActionPreference = $oldErrorAction
```

Comment: `-Properties *` this is a terrible practice and you don't answer the OP's question about the pipelines being `$null`.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: you're right. In this case -Properties mail would suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the careful warning, I guess I should add, this is for new users, who do not yet have a proxyaddress set up at all, there was a miscommunication within IT about who was responsible for this att and now we're trying to go back and fix it as we find the issues, obviously we'd be better off with a proper script, but no one has the time :( instead FLS has been given access to this and is modifying it by hand inside ADUC, that's really annoying so I came up with this powershell line that could do it a bit faster, they also need to modify like three other attributes.

Comment: Also, why not just use `-add`? this will append the new smtp to the old one.

Comment: Sure, if you can be certain the new address you are adding is not already in the list, why not. I just do the `-Clear` to make sure i am totally recreating the proxy addresses with my new array. In your case it is all to do with new users who have nothing in there yet, so you can skip the -Clear. Anyway.. do you feel like your question has been answered by now?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try set the variable first and then call on it in the script.

something like this,

$user = Get-ADUser username -Properties mail | select-object mail

Then write your script and call on the variable you may need to use foreach with a if statement to get it to function the way you want.

Comment: This: `$user = Get-ADUser username -Properties mail | Set-ADUser -replace @{"proxyaddresses"="SMTP:$($user.mail)"}`

Comment: you care not properly writing the command.   You will not be able to pipe in the -replace like that

Comment: try this  $user = Get-ADUser username -Properties mail | select-object mail $replace = $user -replace @{"proxyaddresses"="SMTP:$($user.mail)"}  this may not work but you need to write the command different

Comment: Why are you using select-object? Your suggestion errors on Select-Object : `Select-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$null'.`

Comment: the reason you use select-object is to specify the property you are trying to change or identify.  Get-ADUser   -Identity "username"  -Properties mail,proxyaddresses | Select-Object mail,proxyaddresses..But if you are trying to do a bulk change you should use -searchbase parameter too and do it one OU at a time, but you need to create variable and then call on them in your script that is how i would do it

Comment: Why insist on using a one-liner when you don't know exactly what is being passed through the pipeline? Also, i never had much success with using -replace on a multivalued AD attribute and always use the combination `$user | Set-ADUser -Clear ProxyAddresses; $user | Set-ADUser -Add @{'ProxyAddresses' = @("SMTP:$($user.mail)")}`